# found '0' definitions of operator "**", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "**" in VHDL

Tags: error-handling, vhdl

I am trying to simulate the below code. However, it shows the error " found '0' definitions of operator "**", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "**" ". I have had attached the required packages to my code. please guide me with this error. Thank you in advance.

```
library IEEE;

USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;

USE IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

USE IEEE.math_real.all;

library IEEE_proposed;

use IEEE_proposed.fixed_pkg.all;


entity test_zp is 

end;


Architecture ARCHofZP of test_zp is 

    
    TYPE matrix IS ARRAY ( NATURAL RANGE <>, NATURAL RANGE <> ) OF INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 500;
    
    SIGNAL kernel : matrix ( 1 TO 3 , 1 TO 3 ) := ((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,1));

    SIGNAL image1 : matrix ( 1 To 6 , 1 TO 6 ) := ((25,100,75,49,130,15),(50,80,0,70,100,34),(20,5,10,20,30,0),(45,60,50,12,24,32),(34,37,53,55,21,90),(45,65,55,78,20,16));


    FUNCTION batchnorm (outimg : matrix ( 1 To 8 , 1 TO 8 ) ) RETURN matrix IS
    
    VARIABLE sum1 : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 500;
    
    VARIABLE SD1,SD,mean,ave,sum : UFIXED (10 downto -2):= "00000000";
    
    VARIABLE batchnorm_mat : matrix (outimg'RANGE(1), outimg'RANGE(2));
    
    CONSTANT alpha,beta : UFIXED (1 downto -2):= "0010";
    
        BEGIN 
        
            R1 : FOR i IN outimg'RANGE(1) LOOP
                
                C1 : FOR j IN outimg'RANGE(2) LOOP
                
                    sum1 := sum1 + outimg(i,j);
                
                END LOOP;
                
            END LOOP;
            
            
            mean := sum1 / outimg'LENGTH;
            
            ave := to_ufixed(23,10,-2);
            
            
            R2 : FOR i IN outimg'RANGE(1) LOOP
                
                C2 : FOR j IN outimg'RANGE(2) LOOP
                
                    SD1 := ((to_ufixed(outimg(i,j),10,-2)-ave)/to_ufixed(outimg'LENGTH,10,-2)) + SD1;
                
                END LOOP;
                
            END LOOP;
            
            
            SD := SD1 ** (2);
            
            R3 : FOR i IN batchnorm_mat'RANGE(1) LOOP
            
                C3 : FOR j IN batchnorm_mat'RANGE(2) LOOP
                
                    batchnorm_mat(i,j) := ((to_ufixed(outimg(i,j),10,-2) - ave)/(SD)) * alpha + beta ;
                    
                    END LOOP;
                    
                END LOOP;
            
            RETURN batchnorm_mat; -- return batch normalized outimg matrix named batchnorm_mat
            
    END FUNCTION batchnorm;

        
    begin
    
    outimg <= zero_padding( kernel , image1 );

end Architecture ARCHofZP;
```

Comment: `IEEE_proposed` is not a standard library, and some tools dont have it included - have you included it yourself in your project? Secondly, `std_logic_arith` and `numeric_std` contain conflicting type definitions. You should delete `std_logic_arith` as it is not a standard VHDL package.

Comment: The error message tells you there are either 0 or >1 visible definitions of the operator (for those operands and result). Tricky has pointed out the most likely reason why : namespace pollution from too many USE clauses.

Comment: Not name space pollution. You use neither IEEE packages math_real, numeric_std nor Synopsys std_logic_arith. `outimg` is not declared. The bit string default value of variables `sd1`, `sd`, `mean`, `ave`, and `sum` doesn't match the length specified in the subtype indication (`ufixed (10 downto -2)`, length 13).  You provide function `batchnorm` but call `zero_padding`. Provide a [mcve], please single line space. E.g. `sum1 / outimg'length;` where function parameter `outimg` index 1 (the default) is an integer and sum1 is an integer but the result is the type of `mean` (ufixed).

Comment: Operator "**" is not defined for fixed_pkg, `sd1` has a fraction part.  Operator "+" in `batchnorm_mat(i,j) := ((to_ufixed(outimg(i,j),10,-2) - ave) / (sd)) * alpha + beta;` the left hand operand is type ufixed the result is type integer and beta is integer. Similar to the previously commented "/" there is no implicit conversion to and from ufixed.

Comment: All these **cannot determine exact overloaded...** questions have common cause. Operators are implemented in functions. Which function is determined by operator overload (See, e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008, 4.5 Subprogram overloading, 4.5.2 Operator overloading, 12.5 The context of overloading resolution). A function call has a result value and parameters whose types can be determined from context. For these three operators there are no visible function declarations matching the parameter and result type required by context.